# Cannot update InfluenceScore on Social Profiles programmatically

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

We have a newly set-up CRM  2015 On-Premise environment; and we're doing some fiddling with [the Social Care framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn689039.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

We simply wanted to update a Social Profile record's `InfluenceScore` parameter within our custom application using a web service call, but it appears to have no effect on the field. 
Oddly enough, it *does not throw any exceptions*, and the service call *does not complain* at all. Everything seems normal, except *the field is not being updated*.

Here are the regarding bits of our code;

```
// Retrieving the social profile record with all it's columns
Entity socialProfile = GetSocialProfileByName(socialProfileName);

double score = 0;
string scoreField = "influencescore";

// If socialProfile contains our attribute, set it appropriately, otherwise add the attribute
if(socialProfile.Contains(scoreField)) 
{
    score = socialProfile.GetAttributeValue<float?>(scoreField).GetValueOrDefault(0) + 10; // Add 10 to the existing score.
    socialProfile[scoreField] = score;
}
else 
{
    socialProfile.Attributes.Add(scoreField, 10);
}

// Update the record.
service.Update(socialProfile);
```

- Does Social Care Framework allow the `InfluenceScore` to be updated externally?
- If so, what's the proper way to do it?

Comment: I think you should be first removing the current score and then adding the new one.

Comment: I cannot remove the score or set it to `null` as well, because the SDK is ignoring my `UpdateRequest`s on that field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at the metadata of **socialprofile** entity and found out that the **influencescore** attribute has its [IsValidForUpdate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.metadata.attributemetadata.isvalidforupdate.aspx) property set to False. It can be set on create though (i.e. IsValidForCreate is True).

Comment: First thing I've done was looking it up in the attribute metadata tables too, and, if we set the [`IsValidForUpdate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.metadata.attributemetadata.isvalidforupdate.aspx) property to `true` on the database with a SQL update *(which is highly unsupported to do so)* turns out we *can* update the attribute with an SDK request. But what is the reason behind this? Why would SocialCare want to prevent updates to the `InfluenceScore` property?